# How can I tell that my application was launched / switched to from a localnotification? (SWIFT)

Tags: ios, swift

I saw a few questions regarding this topic and all of them were about implementing a listener function in AppDelegate.swift, but none of those solutions seem to be working for me.
Does anybody have a solution?

I tried this:
[Open view controller when remote notification pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28650468/open-view-controller-when-remote-notification-pressed)

and this: 
[Check for launching from UILocalNotification in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856025/check-for-launching-from-uilocalnotification-in-swift)

unfortunately, none of that works

Comment: Show the code where you create the local notification and your app delegate callback